# Convert a calendar object to json object in android

Tags: android, calendar, json

```
Calendar time;
time=mEvent.getStartTime();                           
mSocket.emit("new message", time);
```

I got this as output on my local server

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1451079047871,
    areFieldsSet=true,
    lenient=true,
    zone=Asia/Kolkata,
    firstDayOfWeek=2,
    minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,
    ERA=1,YEAR=2015,
    MONTH=11,
    WEEK_OF_YEAR=52,
    WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,
    DAY_OF_MONTH=26,
    DAY_OF_YEAR=360,
    DAY_OF_WEEK=7,
    DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,
    AM_PM=0,HOUR=3,
    HOUR_OF_DAY=3,
    MINUTE=0,
    SECOND=47,
    MILLISECOND=871,
    ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,
    DST_OFFSET=0]
```

I want to convert this to **JSONObject** either by getting above string or by using time as object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing date to server then try to pass TimeInMillis to Server.
At server side just get TimeInMillis and there with using Date function you can get fields of Date object you want.

Code:

```
Calendar time;
time=mEvent.getStartTime();    
long start_time=time.getTimeInMillis();
```

TimeinMillis is best way to parse time field between Server and Android Application.
All you need to do is get the desired fields using default Calendar and Date function methods both side.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Gson` to convert the GregorianCalendar to a `JSON string`.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
String json = gson.toJson(cal);
JSONObject cal_json=new JSONObject(json);
```

Comment: This gives me new idea about calendar. But It is good to just use Current time in millis at both side. I have used in my most of Applications and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

To create a date in the W3C XML schema, which is a good format for JSON dates:

```
Calendar myCalendarObj = Calendar.getInstance(); // Snap a moment in time

JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(); // Create a JSON object (org.json.JSONObject)

SimpleDateFormat jsonDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"); // from java.text.SimpleDateFormat
String senddate = jsonDateFormat.format(myCalendarObj.getTime());
jObj.put("a_date_field", senddate);
```